# How the Local State file is creating in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I have created my own custom protocol in chrome for my application. For minimize the alert chrome popup, i have added my custom protocol name in the "Local State" file. So it was working fine. Then i have requirement to add one more custom protocol in Chrome.

Now i have added one more custom protocol in my Chrome "Local State" file, but it was not working anymore. I tried to un-install chrome and installed newly then also it was not working and keep on i can see the pop-up in chrome whenever i try to access that new protocol.

Looks like my "Local State" file has been corrupted and same thing is happening for another machine as well.

May i know how the Chrome is creating Local State file ?

Comment: You'll have to figure out it yourself by analyzing the [source code](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/browser/prefs/browser_prefs.cc?l=339&rcl=fc2e2e83c42d118bdf3dfbd0afde6114205b9874).

Comment: Uninstalling Chrome doesn't remove files in the user's settings, like bookmarks, cookies, and other state. These should be in a Chrome-related folder in the user's directory. If you want to reset it back to defaults, just remove this directory and Chrome will recreate it.

Answer (score 0):

You should detete the original local state file while chrome is off and not on the background. Keep a copy. And replace the file before relaunch.